# OneDrive REST API JSON response

Tags: json, httpresponse, onedrive, live-sdk

I was wondering whether there is a reference which I can follow for getting error codes and error messages of JSON objects in HTTP responses? For example, the following is for uploading failure:

```
"error": {
    "code": "request_body_invalid_media_type", 
    "message": "The Content-Type header 'text/plain' isn't supported." 
}
```

Does Microsoft (OneDrive) provide a list of these error codes and error messages? I need a reference so that I could transform these error status and pass them to another application. Does anyone know where I could find the list of these?

Answer (score 0):

For the comprehensive list of status codes refer MSDN Dev center - [Returned status codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631844.aspx#Returned_status_codes).